# QuickLook does not preview .txt files

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, quicklook

I have the problem that QuickLook does not allow me to preview `.txt` files, despite being plain text. For instance here

[image]

you see—no preview. Pressing `Space` does not help

[image]

However, Spotlight does show me the preview

[image]

How can this be? I am quite sure that originally, text file previews worked.
Could this have to do with MacVim being the default application for this file type? I am on 10.10.4 and have the following QL plugins installed:

- BetterZipQL
- iBooksAuthor
- iWork
- QLColorCode
- qlImageSize
- QLMarkdown
- QLStephen
- QuickLookJSON
- Suspicious Package
- Video
- WebP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the QuickLook Plugin with whatever app you've set as default to open text file. You can probably find that in `Your_Application.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook`.

As [@Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734401/3657151) said:

> Generators embedded in applications are always preferred to plug-ins in ~/Library/QuickLook (which are preferred to the ones in /Library/QuickLook, which are preferred to the ones in /System/Library/QuickLook).

And there is no way to change that preference order. If you want to make sure it's the custom generator you can see the file with the default QL plugin with the following command in Terminal:

```
qlmanage -g /System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator -c public.plain-text -p <path_to_text_file>
```

You can try to delete the app's QL plug-in, that could work but GateKeeper may stop you from opening the app, since it won't match it code signature.

Comment: So what I'm seeing is probably cause by MacVim not having and QL plugin in its app directory, right?

Comment: @oarfish Yes, that is correct. Did you try to use the default QL Plugin from Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this has been made available in the `feature/quicklook` branch in the MacVim repository. See the [github issue here](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/126). I think it has been merged into `master` already. You may need to compile it yourself.